# How do I calculate the surface potential of a conductor given a charge distribution?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, potential, conductors

I have tried the conventional definition but since there is a charge density at the point we want to calculate the potential at, it turns out to be infinity. Now, i dont know how to calculate the sum of all other potentials of points except that of the point of calculation in an integral. Ive been stuck for days trying to do this.

Comment: Itll be better if you add the particular problem. The methods may vary based on the problem.

Comment: As @Lelouch said , $V=\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon r}...$

Comment: If you have a conductor, it generally can't support an arbitrary charge distribution: charge will move to equalize the potential at all points on/in the conductor.

Answer (score 0):

Ill give a general answer applicable to any conductor without cavities which contain charges(you can tweak this approach to satisfy those cases). Let us have a conducting surface $S$ enclosing a volume $V$. The charges exist only at $S$. Let the charge distribution be $\sigma(r, \theta , \phi)$. Consider the following definition of potential at a point $P \in V$:

$U(P) = \int_S \frac{\sigma(r,\theta,\phi).r.d\theta.d\phi}{4\pi\epsilon_0}$.

Using this formula appropriately amd exploiting some other symmetries, you can find the potential an some interior point $P$. Since the metal is an equipotential, and since the potential suffers no discontinuity while crossing a charged surface, the same is the potential of the surface. Or:

$U(P) = U(X) $ for any $X \in S $

Comment: The formula is nothing but u = q/(4pi epsilon. R)which we use for point charges.

Answer (score 0):

Its the other way around. The surface of a conductor has constant potential. Potential is defined up to a free constant, so it may be set to zero. What we don't know is the charge distribution per surface area. This is defining the radial electric field by Gauss/Coulomb/Maxwell equation

$$\text{div}\ \vec D = \rho $$

that reduces to the defining equation for the charge density $\sigma$ per area

$$\sigma = \vec n \cdot \left(\vec D_{out}-  \vec D_{in}\right) $$
on a conductors surface.

If the constant of the potential is set to -V at infinity (or 0 at infinty and V on the surface), the integral theorems yield the potential
$$\Phi(x)=\int_\Sigma \frac{\sigma (y)}{4 \pi |x-y|} d\Sigma $$
with takes the constant value  $\Phi(\Sigma) =V$ everywhere on the surface.

Involved: Minimalization of pair Coulomb energy over all pairs of surface elements in thermal equilibrium of the free electron gas in the conduction band of a metall.